# HQL query to convert blob to string

Tags: hibernate

I have a blob field but i need to select the column as string in the select query.

ex

FROM Employee where employee_file_contents LIKE '%PF%';

where employee_file_contents is a blob column

Thanks.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609862/apply-like-on-blob-field-with-hibernate-mysql) question

Comment: I am looking for a HQL or SQL query